# Where goes a session after I launch lxsession in terminal

Tags: lxsession

If in Lubuntu under LXDE I open LXTerminal and launch "lxsession" command then it sends me to a log-in screen.  When I log in I get to a **new** session.  So do I loose the **first** session from which I launched "lxsesion" command or I still can get back to it somehow?  For example, if I edited some file in that first session and did not save changes before launching "lxsession" is there any way to get back and save the file?